# DocuSign: eSignature API - fill up text field & send template envelope

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I would like to fill up template envelope fields & send it by API.
So in DocuSign eSignature demo app I just created one template with one *.pdf document file:

[Template:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n32hv.png)

And I put there a few fields:
[Fields:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iPBP.png)

With this setup:
[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLD0p.png)

API:
[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSCUM.png)

But the response was terrible wrong:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAW0.png)
And I cannot set the field text by API.

Can somebody please help me what I am doing wrong here ?

What I tried so far is a combinations of failure APIs calls by testing at least on 100 envelopes.
And of course combination of the reference API pages.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- "signer" is not the name of the **templateRole**. You redacted the name of the role in your screenshot, so I cannot know if that's the reason.
- "1" is the wrong **documentId**. I don't know how you added the document to the template, if you did this via the web app - it won't be "1". You can omit this field from the API call if you want.